# pass react grandchildren that call function in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a template modal react component like this (simplified to make my question clearer):

```
function Modal(props) {
    const hide=()=>{
        document.querySelector('#modal').style.display='none';
    };

    return (
        <div id = 'modal' className='modal'>
           {props.children}
           //close button and so on...
        </div>
    );
}

export default Modal;
```

Now I am making a more specific version of the modal for a specific purpose. So I pass the `Modal` functional component `children` that will be grandchildren of the `AreYouSureModal`:

```
function AreYouSureModal(props) {

    yesAction = ()=>{props.yesAction}
    noAction = ()=>{props.noAction}
    const children = <fragment>
        Are you sure?
        <button onclick = {this.yesAction /*and call .hide() in Modal*/}>Yes</button>
        <button onclick = {this.noAction /*and call .hide() in Modal*/}>No</button>    
    </fragment>;

    return <Modal children = {children} />
}

export default AreYouSureModal;
```

Now the `yesAction` and `noAction` are going to be something I got from the parent of the `AreYouSureModal`, so I'm passing those functions. But those buttons also need to call the `hide()` function that's in the template `Modal` functional component. What is the best way to do this?

Do I make the `yesAction` function in the `AreYouSureModal` call the methods of the `Modal` child? Or do I make the `Modal` a constant in the `AreYouSureModal` function and bind those methods to the constant before I pass it?

In other words, how do I create grandchildren that call a function in a child? Or am I trying to do this in completely the wrong way altogether?

Comment: @MTCoster Yeah, sorry, fixed it. I guess there isn't a reason for a `.yesAction()` in this at all but there might be other stuff in there.

Comment: If you’re finding yourself passing things *up* the chain in React, you should stop and re-read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: I know you're trying to help but that's a pretty vague and not very useful comment. I have read that document. I can easily believe I'm not following its principles correctly, but just telling me to read it again is as close to useless as possible. I could just tell someone with a C question they should read The C Programming Language (Second Edition) since the answer is definitely in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the modal with styles I recommend making the modal using [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). Disclaimer: I haven't gotten into using hooks yet so I'm gonna write this using class-components.

Anyway, then your `Modal`-component would look something like this:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.isOpen) return null

    return (
      ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div className="modal">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Then your `AreYouSureModal`-component would look something like this:

```
class AreYouSureModal extends React.Component {
  handleYesAction = () => {
    /* Do something */
    this.props.onClose()
  }

  handleNoAction = () => {
    /* Do something */
    this.props.onClose()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <h2>Are you sure?</h2>
          <button onClick={this.handleYesAction}>Yes</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleNoAction}>No</button>    
         </React.Fragment>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

And then finally, the component that you're rendering the `AreYouSureModal` from, would hold the state for the modal:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isAreYouSureModalOpen: false }

  openAreYouSureModal = () => this.setState({ isAreYouSureModalOpen: true })

  closeAreYouSureModal = () => this.setState({ isAreYouSureModalOpen: false })

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.openAreYouSureModal}>Open modal</button>

        <AreYouSureModal
          onClose={this.closeAreYouSureModal}
          isOpen={this.state.isAreYouSureModalOpen}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer. I'm not 100% sure I want to do it this way; I was hoping to keep the modals as functional components instead of classes. But if I don't get anything like what I was hoping for I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer. You can have the Modal and AreYouSureModal as functional components instead of class components since they are stateless.